# rails3-jquery-autocomplete redirect on select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem. It works perfectly, but I don't know how to implement a redirect on selection of a result. All it does now is populate the field with the text of the selected result. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to perform re-direct when a user selects one of the drop down items from the autocomplete list when using rails3-jquery-autocomplete is via the "railsAutocomplete.select" event, which is triggered when the user selects one of the options.

How to do this is documented [here](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete#running-custom-code-on-selection). This approach means you can avoid editing the rails3-jquery-autocomplete code, and only causes a re-direct to happen when the user selects from the drop down option, rather than "onChange" of the form field, which isn't really what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `onChange` event for the textfield which gets updated. The redirect you can achieve with some simple javascript:

```
window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com"
```

If you need different redirects for different values, use `switch`:

```
var location;

switch ( document.getElementById('#my_textfield').value ) {
  case "stackoverflow":
    location = "http://stackoverflow.com";
  case "google":
    location = "http://google.com";
  default:
    location = "http://mysite.com";
}

window.location.href = location;
```

Comment: Did this work? If it worked, could you please accept the answer? Otherwise tell me what went wrong, and I will try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the jquery-ui.js file in assets, you will find it minified

go to http://jsbeautifier.org and make the code look better

look for the line containing this

```
case e.ENTER:
```

you will find it blank, this is the action that will be performed on clicking Enter so change it to

```
case e.ENTER:
 window.location.href = 'yourURL';
```